# android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am working with Fragments which implements an interface.

```
public class SigninFragment extends Fragment implements SigninInterface
```

The interface's method implementation in the fragment class is as follows.

```
@Override
public void afterSubmitClicked(String userId, Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d(TAG,"Calling time afterSubmitClicked called"+bundle);
    
    if(!userId.equals("-1")){
        //Logged in successfully
        //Move to MusicHome
        
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MusicHome.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("SigninFragment.user_details", bundle);
        startActivity(mIntent);
        
    }else{
        //Logging in failed
        //show error dialog
    }
    
}
```

This method is called after exectuting a AsynchronousTask (which extends AsyncTask) class.

But I am getting crash.
And the error message shows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

**Logcat**

```
   02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177): Process: com.raaga.android, PID: 28177
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3996)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.raaga.fragments.SigninFragment.afterSubmitClicked(SigninFragment.java:152)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.raaga.asynctask.SignInAsyncTask.onPostExecute(SignInAsyncTask.java:92)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.raaga.asynctask.SignInAsyncTask.onPostExecute(SignInAsyncTask.java:1)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-14 16:37:04.648: E/AndroidRuntime(28177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have found the mistake what I did. 
We need to get the activity instance from the override method OnAttach()
For example,

```
public MainActivity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Then pass the activity as context as following.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(activity, MusicHome.class);
```

Comment: Seems like an android bug to me, but nice work around, fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Why getActivity() won't work and the reference will?

Comment: getting null on getActivity() is weird but yeah nice work around.  i've been scratching my head on this

Comment: onAttach is deprecated

Comment: @Menna-AllahSami `onAttach(Context context)` is not.

Comment: @oldergod according to this official link it is deprecated since API23 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)

Comment: @Menna-AllahSami The one taking an Activity as a parameter, yes. The one taking a context is not.

Comment: Yes I know , I mean the mentioned function in the answer

Comment: The one taking context is never called. You should use the deprecated method for now.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405397/cannot-solve-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-string-android-content @KarthikeyanVe

Comment: I don't know how this fixes the problem, but it works.

Comment: Can you provide a solution for Kotlin?

Answer (score 51):

The answers to this question helped me find my problem, but my source was different, so hopefully this can shed light on someone finding this page searching for answers to the 'random' context crash:

I had specified a SharedPreferences object, and tried to instantiate it at it's class-level declaration, like so:

```
public class MyFragment extends FragmentActivity {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
```

Referencing `this` before the onCreate caused the *"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"* error for me.

Instantiating the object inside the onCreate() solved my problem, like so:

```
public class MyFragment extends FragmentActivity {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had the same problem while calling getDefaultSharedPreferences() from Application class constructor (public class MyApplication extends Application). Your message helped to see that I should move it to the onCreate method.

Comment: Nice tip, helped me a lot

Answer (score 25):

android API level 23.

Use

> getContext()

instead of

> getActivity()

getActivity()  gives the parent Activity, a Context object

Here You can use

> MyActivity.this

instead of

> getActivity() / getApplicationContext()

Comment: I get the same NPE using getContext()

Comment: some phones gets NPE with MyActivity.this (one plus and lenovo for example )

Comment: @DagnogoJean-François how to solve it for those phones?

Comment: Might be working for others, but not working for me. I was using `Fragment`.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem trying to show a Toast in a fragment.

After some debugging I found out that I was removing the fragment before calling:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Because the **fragment had been removed**, the context became null, causing the exception.

Simple solution: call the `getContext()` **before removing** the fragment.

Answer (score 10):

In my case the error occurred inside a `Fragment` on this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondaryActivity.class);
```

It happened when I double clicked on an item which triggered the code above so two `SecondaryActivity.class` activities were launched at the same time, one on top of the other. I closed the top `SecondaryActivity.class` activity by pressing back button which triggered a call to `getActivity()` in the `SecondaryActivity.class` which came to foreground. The call to `getActivity()` returned `null`.
It's some kind of weird Android bug so it usually should not happen.
You can block the clicks after the user clicked once.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had a onCLick method in a recyclerview adapter,Context context; at the beginning.

```
 holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StoryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("STORY", mComments.get(position));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

And i changed to get the context from the current view

```
 holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), StoryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("STORY", mComments.get(position));
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that I was passing Activity to the constructor, not Context

```
public Adapter(Activity activity, List<MediaItem> items, boolean can) {
    mItems = items;
    canEdit = can;
    mActivity = activity;
}
```

and using this activity to getDefaultSharedPreferences(), so I changed the Activity to Context and I was still calling the Adapter constructor with MainActivity.this

Answer (score 3):

You only need to do this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
```

Comment: in the fragment ?

Answer (score 2):

My class is not extends to Activiti.
I solved the problem this way.

```
class MyOnBindViewHolder : LogicViewAdapterModel.LogicAdapter {
          ...
 holder.title.setOnClickListener({v->
                v.context.startActivity(Intent(context,  HomeActivity::class.java))
            })
          ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put fragment name before the activity

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SigninFragment.this.getActivity(),MusicHome.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You solve the issue with a try/ catch.
This crash happens when user close the app before the start intent.

```
try
{
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MusicHome.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("SigninFragment.user_details", bundle);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Great answer. This was exactly what was happening to me. I had a countdowntimer that would create an intent in the `onFinish` method. But if the user pressed the back button to go to the previous activity where the timer was not created, then I would get a null object reference since getActivity() would no longer work. This could also be useful for threads that weren't closed after the user left the activity. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem easily and use your activity anywhere in the activity, just store activity like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
      Context context = this;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {....}

      AnotherClass {
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("key", "value");
          startActivity(intent);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to `onAttach` is deprecated in API23 and above...
In my Fragment, I declare and set `parentActivity` before hand everytime when I go into Fragment. Most likely happen due to when we pressed back button caused the context to become null. Therefore below is my solution.

```
private Activity parentActivity;

public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        parentActivity = getActivity();
//...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Messages> mMessageList) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mMessageList = mMessageList;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use in global

```
Context context;
```

and create a constructor and passing the context.
LoginClass is name of the class

```
LoginClass(Context context)
{this.context=context;}
```

and also when we call the class then use `getApplicationContext`
like
`LoginClass lclass =  new LoginClass(getApplicationContext)`
thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If this error happened when getting `context` , is means you are remove the context before calling it. Lets say if you are willing to get `Toast` in the `fragment` and you remove the `fragment` before call the `Toast`.

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

So solution is either wait to `Toast` happens to remove or change the fragment, or remove the `Toast` or any thing that needs to `context` before change or remove the `fragment`.

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin

```
lateinit var views:View?
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     views=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
   Toast.makeText(views.context ,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   return views;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes `startActivity` method throws an exception like especially in `Fragments`:

Calling `startActivity()` from outside of an `Activity` context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. Is this really what you want?

So you should `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` method