# how can i start other screen from cardview

Tags: android

I'm trying to start a new screen on touch of card view from holder class but when i clicking on card view app crashes ..
 Here is my code for RecyclerViewHolders class

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTitle);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cardImages);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

code for RecyclerViewAdapter class

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

```
private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private Context context;
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}
```

}

When i'm trying to start other screen from RecyclerViewHolder class my App is crashing plz guide me ...

Comment: and add your getAdapterPosition method too

Comment: check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/a/30498143/2826147

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),SecondActivity.class));
```

Hope its helpful ..

Comment: This is not working showing error ClassCastException

Comment: in your code there is only one place where `ClassCastException` can occur,   when you casting your views to `TextView` and `ImageView` check if views represented by that ids in layout xml correspond to view classes which you're trying to cast

Comment: A little bit modification i my RecyclerViewAdapter class and this code is working .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help