# Getting error while stopping foreground service in watch from mobile

Tags: android, wear-os

From my mobile I am starting a foreground service in my android watch. I am able to do that correctly. But when I try to stop the service as well as the activity in watch , I am getting an error message( watch app is crashing). I am using message listener service to receive the message from mobile.

I also have a stop button in watch app which is running perfectly(if I try to stop the service from watch itself) and it has the same lines of code. I am not sure where I am wrong when I receive message from mobile app to stop the foreground service.

```
@Override public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    Log.i(INFOTAG, "Stop msg received");

    if(messageEvent.getPath().equals(STOP_MESSAGE_PATH_2)){

        started = false;

        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(
                MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
        stopService(stopIntent);

        this.finish();

    }
}
```

Below is the error log I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4160)
at com.magi.magidemo.MainActivity.onMessageReceived(MainActivity.java:464)
at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzcf$5.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzcf$5.zzs(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmn.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmn$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `Activity`'s instance from the override method.

Like this:

```
public MainActivity activity;

// in the override method

this.activity = activity;
```

Then use it:

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent(
            activity, ForegroundService.class);
```

Have a look: [android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515049/android-content-context-getpackagename-on-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: Hi, how to use the Activity's instance in onMessageReceived override method? Please advise.

Comment: Add the first line in your Activity, i think the problem is coming from `**this**.finish();` and `Intent stopIntent = new Intent(
            activity`, seems to be good. it should work with my answer. take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30498143/4409113

Comment: Hi, the activity is actually closing. Only problem is that the foreground service is running with error message. I tried it. Still getting error.