# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName() on getActivity()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

When I try to create an intent on my Fragment class to move my activity page *HomeScreenActivity* using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

I'm getting following error `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` on [Fabric](https://fabric.io). I got this error on **Galaxy S7 Edge** with os version **7**. While executing line `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeScreenActivity.class);` (Line number *338 on LoginFragment.java*)

Here is the full log I got from on [Fabric](https://fabric.io),

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
       at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
       at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:5359)
       at com.example.android.fragments.LoginFragment.handleValidateEmployeeResponse(LoginFragment.java:338)
       at com.example.android.fragments.LoginFragment.access$100(LoginFragment.java:53)
       at com.example.android.fragments.LoginFragment$3.onResponse(LoginFragment.java:249)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515049/android-content-context-getpackagename-on-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: @JohnJoe : How to solve this ? How to avoid duplication?

Comment: Have you tried `MyActivity.this` ?

Comment: Please show the entire `handleValidateEmployeeResponse` method

Comment: @John This code is in a Fragment class

Comment: @cricket_007 The most upvoted answer from the link I sent  in Fragment too

Comment: @John Yes, and that isn't a using `MainActivity.this `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `attach` method

```
public Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

And use like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, HomeScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
mActivity.finish();
```

Comment: Let me try this method.

Comment: Good luck to you.@SHIDHIN.T.S

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this,

Take **`Activity`** reference like

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

Then pass the object where you want it, like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity , HomeScreenActivity.class);
activity.finish();
```

Comment: `getActivity()` will still return null depending where it's used