# Call PreferenceFragment class with oncreate method from another class

Tags: android-intent

I'm trying to call this class below from an `AlertDialog`.. I tried `Intent` but I always get `exception`.
code that calls Switchoff class:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Premium.this, Switchoff.class );
                        startActivity( intent );
```

The class I'm trying to call:

```
public  class Switchoff extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final SwitchPreference vibrateSwitch = (SwitchPreference) findPreference( getString( R.string.pref_vibrate_switch_enabled ) );
    vibrateSwitch.setChecked(false);
}
```

}

the error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:142)
```

PS: - I need to keep both findPreference(), and onCreate() method
    - Both class (Premium.class, Switchoff.class) are registed in the Manifest file

THANK YOU FOR EVERY HELP!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515049/android-content-context-getpackagename-on-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: I tryied that solution and the error still persist

Comment: this is also a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) duplicate and it's off-topic, because it does not provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... besides it clearly reads `getPackageName()` and not `findPreference()`. maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere) helps?